# group and collect document based on field in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have notifications collection with this schema

```
_const notificationsSchema = new Schema({
  _from: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User',
  },
  _to: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User',
  },
  _target: String,
  type: {
   type: String,
 },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

[image: screenshot]

How to group notifications like facebook " and 50 others liked your post"?

How to retrieve this shape of data, for the documents that has same _parent?

```
[
{
  _id: "",
  _to: "",
  _parent: "",
  lastThreeUsers: [_ from, ...],
  count: 50
}
]
```

Comment: why do you have underscores on `const` and your `schema` property names?

Comment: Also, I am not sure what you are asking. Could you clarify your question further? What do you mean for records that has same parent? What defines a parent?

Comment: i use underscore as a convention for foreign key,... the code: const Notifications = mongoose.model('Notifications', notificationsSchema);

Comment: Then target/const should not have _ since one is a javascript keyword and the other is simply a string type? I

Comment: So basically you want to be able to count how many people like a certain post?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. yes exactly what i want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very open ended response. There is no one right answer. I have provided both a naive and ideal approach to the problem. You may think of another, better way.

You would need to have a something along the lines of a "Likes" collection where you store all likes from users where each like has a reference to the post being liked. Then you would have to perform an aggregation on the likes collection to get all the likes where the postId is equal to the id of the post you want total likes for.

First attempt that.

Then a better, "real world" approach is to also add a "likesCount" (call it what you want) property onto Post documents that keeps tracks of the likes on the post. Update the likesCount each time a user likes/dislikes that post. This way you won't actually have to search through the "Likes" collection over and over again everytime your have to show that data.

Comment: I already have Likes collection. but the problem here, i have more than type of notifications, such as like, comment, reply. so when i retrieve notifications, i see like this! <user1> likes your post "xyz", <user2> likes your post "xyz" ..., i need to group this notifications and appear as one notifications like <user1> and 2 others liked your post "xyz"

Comment: can you clarify you comment? I am not sure I understand

Comment: I updated my answer with screenshot. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYZqW.png,  suppose that i have Notifications collection, and parent field return to post id, and user1 liked my post, to this will save in Notifcations collecation that user1 likes post "xyz". and user2 liked my port "xyz", will save another document in Notifications collection that user2 liked post "xyz", when i retrieve Notifications documents, it will return [ user1 liked post "xyz", user2 liked post "xyz"], so i need to return one document for same post. such as user2 and 3 others liked your post "xyz"